# plugin rake task should be in li/taks deprecation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-plugins

WARNING: Rake tasks in {plugin name}  tasks are deprecated. Use lib/tasks instead.

found a deprecation of plugin tasks path, plugins news version are installed, but they have not updated for fix this deprecation. Now i want to remove this deprecation without moving tasks folder in lib. 
is there some other solution for remove this deprecation except physically moving tasks of plugin into plugin's lib folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can't having this deprecation warning without fix it. But you can output it in 3 way :

```
config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr
config.active_support.deprecation = :log
config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
```